# syntax error at or near "CREATE" when making a trigger in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

i'm trying to make a trigger that checks when a row is entered into a table if a certain value in that row exists in another table.
the tables i have are:

*car, rent, request*

the code i'm using:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigf1() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT seats FROM car WHERE lno=new.lno;

IF seats=!(SELECT seats FROM request WHERE rno=new.rno)
THEN
raise exception 'assignment contradicts design'
END IF;
RETURN null;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER 'T1' BEFORE INSERT ON rent
for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf1( );
```

I get an error saying:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CREATE"

> LINE 13: CREATE TRIGGER 'T1' BEFORE INSERT IN rent

anyone knows why?

Comment: Identifiers are written without single quotes: `create trigger t1 ...`

Comment: still gives the same error :(

Comment: This `$$` needs to be `$$;`. Without it you did not finish the function code.

Answer (score 0):

well, don't know why but this solved it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trigf1() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
SELECT seats FROM car WHERE lno=new.lno;

IF seats=!(SELECT seats FROM request WHERE rno=new.rno)
THEN
raise exception 'assignment contradicts design';
END IF;
RETURN null;
END;
$$language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER T1 BEFORE INSERT ON rent
for each row
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigf1( );
```

I could use an explanation if anyone knows why :)

Comment: You were missing a `;` after the `$$`